# What is the switching button element in Android compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need the UI element for compose Android that looks like on the picture. Is there any idea? After clicking on left it becomes active and right become white.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just combined two separate buttons with rounded corners with this `RoundedCornerShape`

```
Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStartPercent = 25, bottomStartPercent = 25)) {

    }
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, shape = RoundedCornerShape(topEndPercent = 25, bottomEndPercent = 25)) {

    }
```

Comment: This sure is the answer. just wrap these two buttons in a `Row`